# Physical interpretation of $U$ and $V$ matrices in SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, eigenvalues

I have a question about the physical interpretation of $U$ and $V$ matrices in SVD.

I collect measurements at multiple devices across time are collected into an $m$ × $T$ matrix $M$, where m is the number of measurements at one time instant, and $T$ is the number of time steps. The matrix $M$ can often be approximated by a low-rank matrix with rank $r$ much less than $m$ and $T$. In [1], authors remark that a low-rank matrix $M_r$ can be computed such as,

[image]

I am not able to understand why $U_r$ will characterize correlations between measurements and $V_r$ the dominant system dynamics. I understand the matrices $U_r$ and $V_r$ correspond to the eigenvectors for $M_rM_r^T$ and $M_r^TM_r$ . What is the physical meaning of $U_r$ and $V_r$ in this context?

[1] Li, W., Wang, M. and Chow, J.H., 2018. Real-time event identification through low-dimensional subspace characterization of high-dimensional synchrophasor data. IEEE Transactions on Power Systems, 33(5), pp.4937-4947.

Comment: Unless "characterize correlations" is taken in an extremely vague sense, the quotation has a chance of being correct only when the expectations of all the measurements are zero.